# I get a SQL Syntax Problem The Error is (Error Code 3780)

Tags: mysql, sql

Together I try to make a Foreign Key for my MySQL Table.
In the picture below I wanna Show how I try to add the Foreign Key.
MySQL Server version is 8.0.25

[image: The Picture of my Commandline]

Comment: Because `Medikamente.id` is `unsigned int` while `Vergabe.MedikametenID` is just `int`. It must match exactly

Comment: The error seems very clear to me. Where is the confusion?

Comment: No images, please. I can't read that tiny text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is due to:

in your **vergabes** table, `MedikametenID` is not **unsigned**. Edit that and tell me if it worked

Comment: @CakePlaysHD you're welcome :) ! (PS. Don't forget to mark this answer as the best answer)

Answer (score 0):

The error message really says it all - when creating a foreign key on a column the type of the column should match the type of the column it's referencing. Here, one of them is an `int` and the other is an `unsigned int`. You should change one of them to match the other before creating a foreign key.